# text-align:justify on a generated evoPDF

Tags: pdf-conversion, evopdf

I am using evoPDF to convert HTML files and it seems that `text-align:justify` is not behaving properly. The spacing happens in between characters, instead of in between words.

What i have used so far without any success:
`letter-spacing:0;`
`text-justify: inter-word;`
Set  `!important` to each of those.

Current Result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysv33.png)
Expected Result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YXeP.png)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

As text-justify [not supported by many browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-justify) and the way you are using the property it would be safer to use word-spacing as an alternative. According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify#Syntax) inter-word is just a variation of the word-spacing property.

You could also try changing the HTTP User-Agent header for the conversion to an agent that may support the property. However, changing the header is is unlikely to affect the outcome.